# How to use mutations and actions in Vuex?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I really want to understand about how to use Vuex in Nuxt.Js.
So I tried to make small apps to confirm mutations and actions in Vuex.

I tried to make count app to use Vuex.
If I click + button in component, variable number will change through mutaions and
get number throught state.
But I ran my code and error occurred like below.

```
[vuex] unknown local mutation type: setCount, global type: count/setCount
```

first of all,
I made a count.ts in store folder of Nuxt.Js project like following.

```
    interface State  {
    count:number
}
const state = () => ({
    count:0
})
const getters = {
    count:(state:State) => {
        return state.count
    }   
}
const mutaions = {
    setCount:(state:State,count:number)=>{
        state.count = count+1;
    }
}
export default { state, getters, mutaions}
```

And then I made Count.vue in pages like following.

```
    <template>
    <div>
        <h2>Counter</h2>
        <p>count:{{count}}</p>
        <v-btn color="primary" @click="setCount">+</v-btn>
    </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, namespace, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'
const Count = namespace('count')

@Component({})
export default class extends Vue{
    @Count.State count:any
    @Count.Mutation setCount!:Function
}
</script>
```

I wanted to change number through mutation, but my tried was failed.
So I tried to make actions to change state.
I edited my code like that.

count.ts↓

```
    interface State  {
    count:number
}
const state = () => ({
    count:0
})
const getters = {
    count:(state:State) => {
        return state.count
    }   
}
const mutaions = {
    setCount:(state:State,count:number)=>{
        state.count = count;
    }
}
const actions = {
    increment:({commit}:any,state:{count:number})=>{
        commit('setCount',state.count +1)
    },
    decrement:({commit}:any,state:{count:number})=>{
        commit('setCount',state.count-1)
    }
}
export default { state, getters, mutaions, actions}
```

Count.vue ↓

```
    <template>
    <div>
        <h2>Counter</h2>
        <p>count:{{count}}</p>
        <v-btn color="primary" @click="increment">+</v-btn>
        <v-btn color="error" @click="decrement">-</v-btn>
    </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, namespace, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'
const Count = namespace('count')

@Component({})
export default class extends Vue{
    @Count.State count:any
    @Count.Mutation increment!:Function
    @Count.Action decrement!:Function    
}
</script>
```

But these code also occurred error again like that.

```
[vuex] unknown local mutation type: increment, global type: count/increment
```

I really want to know how to change variable of state through mutations or actions.
Could anyone advise me?

Comment: export default { state, getters, mutaions, namespaced: true}

Comment: `const Module = namespace(path/to/module)`